# Change Sklearn Make Classification Classes

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

Using `make_classification` from `sklearn` for a binary classification problem, i get labels `0` and `1`. Is there anyway i can change it to get `-1` instead of `0`?

Comment: You can easily replace `label` column of your dataframe to get `-1`s instead of `0`s. Like this: `df.replace(0, -1)`

Comment: @alirezafnatica well, i am not using `pandas`, but after reading your comment, i just did a `for` loop to change the `0`  for `-1` in my array.

Comment: Always take the easier approach :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
import numpy as np

X,y = make_classification()
y_transformed = np.where(y==0,-1,1)
```